# Bash command error when connecting to Coinbase API

Tags: bash, coinbase-api

I am trying to follow Coinbase's steps for setting up an API to price data (https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/price-data).

However, when I type the command "from coinbase.wallet.client import Client" in to my AWS Cloud9 BASH terminal, I get the error "bash: from: command not found". Please help!

Comment: That's not shell scripting, that's python, try it inside your python CLI. To be fair, the word `python` does not appear on that entire page, but the previous  mention of `pip install coinbase` should have made it clear.

Comment: Thanks Marc! For anyone else who might stumble across this post, the code should be: (api_key='xyz', api_secret='uvw',api_version='2018-01-13'), not the placeholder Coinbase specifies